# Get element content without displaying on page in Polymer

Tags: javascript, html, css, polymer

I am building a custom element with Polymer 1.0 and need to get the content inside the tag using javascipt without it being displayed on the page. I tried using the `<content>` tag and fetching it inside the javascript with a query selector. This works except it displays on the page even if I use a `style="display: none;"` attribute. How can I get the content inside the tag without it displaying on the page?

Comment: Can you give us more information about what kind of content, if it is just data about the element you can put it on the elements prototype with a getter to access it. Without a little more information I'm not sure if my answers are what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what exactly your use-case is, but how about simply wrapping your `<content>` tag with a hidden `<div>`?

```
<dom-module id="x-test">
  <template>
    <div hidden>
      <content id="content"></content>
    </div>
  </template>
  <script>
    Polymer({
      is: "x-test",
      attached: function () {
        // access distributed content like this
        var myContent = Polymer.dom(this.$.content).getDistributedNodes();
      }
    });
  <script>
</dom-module>
```